# How can I convert minutes or hours or days to seconds and send it to API in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I am creating an app where user can choose the frequency unit (seconds, minutes, hours or days) and write the frequency value in the input. I have to send the value to the server in seconds so I have to convert it. When I send the frequency value in seconds everything is great, but I have a problem with converting that value to minutes, hours or days. For example, when I try to send 10 minutes, server get the frequency value of "10", instead of "600" (10 minutes * 60 seconds).
Can you tell me what's wrong in my code?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { addSensor } from '../actions/sensors';

class AddSensorPage extends Component {
  state = {  
    name: '',
    category: '',
    frequencyUnit: '',
    frequency: '',
    minValue: '',
    maxValue: ''
  }

  static propTypes = {
    addSensor: PropTypes.func.isRequired
  }

  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    })
  }

  handleCategorySelect = e => {
    this.setState({ category: e.target.value })
  }

  handleFrequencyUnitSelect = e => {
    this.setState({ frequencyUnit: e.target.value })
  }

  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const { name, category, frequency, frequencyUnit } = this.state;

    // Validation
    if (frequencyUnit === 'seconds') {
      this.setState({
        minValue: '30',
        maxValue: '21474836',
      })
    }

    if (frequencyUnit === 'minutes') {
      this.setState({
        minValue: '1',
        maxValue: '357913',
        frequency: this.state.frequency * 60
      })
    }

    if (this.state.frequencyUnit === 'hours') {
      this.setState({
        minValue: '1',
        maxValue: '5965',
        frequency: frequency * 3600
      })
    }

    if (this.state.frequencyUnit === 'days') {
      this.setState({
        minValue: '1',
        maxValue: '248',
        frequency: frequency * 86400
      })
    }

    const sensor = { name, category, frequency };

    this.props.addSensor(sensor);

    this.setState({
      name: '',
      category: '',
      frequencyUnit: '',
      frequency: ''
    })
  }

  render() { 
    return (  
      <div className="col-md-6 m-auto">
        <div className="card card-body mt-5">
          <h2 className="text-center">Add sensor</h2>
          <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label>Name</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                className="form-control"
                name="name"
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                value={this.state.name}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label>Category</label>
              <select className="form-control" onChange={this.handleCategorySelect} value={this.state.category}>
                <option></option>
                <option value="temperature">Temperature sensor</option>
                <option value="humidity">Humidity sensor</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label>Frequency</label>
              <select className="form-control" onChange={this.handleFrequencyUnitSelect} value={this.state.frequencyUnit}>
                <option></option>
                <option value="seconds">Seconds</option>
                <option value="minutes">Minutes</option>
                <option value="hours">Hours</option>
                <option value="days">Days</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <input
                type="number"
                className="form-control"
                name="frequency"
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                value={this.state.frequency}
                placeholder="Value..."
                min={this.state.minValue}
                max={this.state.maxValue}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <button className="btn btn-primary">Dodaj</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(null, { addSensor })(AddSensorPage);
```

Comment: Why do you have to set the state inside handleSubmit for calculation the frequency, since you are going to reset the state again to the initial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because setState works asynchronously

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { addSensor } from '../actions/sensors';

class AddSensorPage extends Component {
  state = {
    name: "",
    category: "",
    frequencyUnit: "",
    frequency: "",
    minValue: "",
    maxValue: ""
  };

  static propTypes = {
    addSensor: PropTypes.func.isRequired
  };

  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
  };

  handleCategorySelect = e => {
    this.setState({ category: e.target.value });
  };

  handleFrequencyUnitSelect = e => {
    this.setState({ frequencyUnit: e.target.value });
  };

  callBack = () => {
    let sensor = {};
    sensor = {
      name: this.state.name,
      category: this.state.category,
      frequency: this.state.frequency
    };
    console.log(sensor);
    this.props.addSensor(sensor);
    this.setState({
      name: "",
      category: "",
      frequencyUnit: "",
      frequency: ""
    });
  };

  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const { name, category, frequency, frequencyUnit } = this.state;

    // Validation

    if (frequencyUnit === "seconds") {
      this.setState(
        {
          minValue: "30",
          maxValue: "21474836"
        },
        () => {
          this.callBack();
        }
      );
    }

    if (frequencyUnit === "minutes") {
      this.setState(
        {
          minValue: "1",
          maxValue: "357913",
          frequency: frequency * 60
        },
        () => {
          this.callBack();
        }
      );
    }

    if (this.state.frequencyUnit === "hours") {
      this.setState(
        {
          minValue: "1",
          maxValue: "5965",
          frequency: frequency * 3600
        },
        () => {
          this.callBack();
        }
      );
    }

    if (this.state.frequencyUnit === "days") {
      this.setState(
        {
          minValue: "1",
          maxValue: "248",
          frequency: frequency * 86400
        },
        () => {
          this.callBack();
        }
      );
    }
    // console.log("This is the sensor", sensor);

  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="col-md-6 m-auto">
        <div className="card card-body mt-5">
          <h2 className="text-center">Add sensor</h2>
          <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label>Name</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                className="form-control"
                name="name"
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                value={this.state.name}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label>Category</label>
              <select
                className="form-control"
                onChange={this.handleCategorySelect}
                value={this.state.category}
              >
                <option />
                <option value="temperature">Temperature sensor</option>
                <option value="humidity">Humidity sensor</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label>Frequency</label>
              <select
                className="form-control"
                onChange={this.handleFrequencyUnitSelect}
                value={this.state.frequencyUnit}
              >
                <option />
                <option value="seconds">Seconds</option>
                <option value="minutes">Minutes</option>
                <option value="hours">Hours</option>
                <option value="days">Days</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <input
                type="number"
                className="form-control"
                name="frequency"
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                value={this.state.frequency}
                placeholder="Value..."
                min={this.state.minValue}
                max={this.state.maxValue}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <button className="btn btn-primary">Dodaj</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

//export default AddSensorPage;
export default connect(null, { addSensor })(AddSensorPage);
```

Here is a working codesandbox example too:
[example](https://codesandbox.io/s/setstateasync-5qsnh?file=/src/AddSensorPage.js)

Answer (score 0):

You are depending on the same state and trying to get value in your code. Why don't you derive it simply?

```
if (frequencyUnit === "minutes") {
  this.setState({
    minValue: "1",
    maxValue: "357913",
    frequency
  });
}
```

and

```
const sensor = {
  name,
  category,
  frequency: frequency * multiplier[frequencyUnit]
};
```

where `multiplier` is:

```
const multiplier = {
  seconds: 1,
  minutes: 60,
  hours: 3600,
  days: 86400
};
```

Still, not the best way. It is not so wise setting the state in the submit part like that. **Again, this is a naive approach. You should think about setting the app state more wisely.**

Here is a better approach:

```js
const units = {
  seconds: {
    name: "seconds",
    multiplier: 1,
    minValue: "30",
    maxValue: "21474836"
  },
  minutes: {
    name: "minutes",
    multiplier: 60,
    minValue: "1",
    maxValue: "357913"
  },
  hours: { name: "hours", multiplier: 3600, minValue: "1", maxValue: "5965" },
  days: { name: "days", multiplier: 86400, minValue: "1", maxValue: "248" }
};

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    name: "",
    category: "",
    frequencyUnit: {},
    frequency: "",
    minValue: "",
    maxValue: ""
  };

  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
  };

  handleCategorySelect = e => {
    this.setState({ category: e.target.value });
  };

  handleFrequencyUnitSelect = e => {
    this.setState({ frequencyUnit: units[e.target.value] });
  };

  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const { name, category, frequency, frequencyUnit } = this.state;

    const sensor = {
      name,
      category,
      frequency: frequency * frequencyUnit.multiplier
    };

    console.log(sensor);
    //this.props.addSensor(sensor);

    this.setState({
      name: "",
      category: "",
      frequencyUnit: {},
      frequency: ""
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="col-md-6 m-auto">
        <div className="card card-body mt-5">
          <h2 className="text-center">Add sensor</h2>
          <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label>Name</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                className="form-control"
                name="name"
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                value={this.state.name}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label>Category</label>
              <select
                className="form-control"
                onChange={this.handleCategorySelect}
                value={this.state.category}
              >
                <option />
                <option value="temperature">Temperature sensor</option>
                <option value="humidity">Humidity sensor</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label>Frequency</label>
              <select
                className="form-control"
                onChange={this.handleFrequencyUnitSelect}
                value={this.state.frequencyUnit.name || ""}
              >
                <option />
                <option value="seconds">Seconds</option>
                <option value="minutes">Minutes</option>
                <option value="hours">Hours</option>
                <option value="days">Days</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <input
                type="number"
                className="form-control"
                name="frequency"
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                value={this.state.frequency}
                placeholder="Value..."
                min={this.state.frequencyUnit.minValue}
                max={this.state.frequencyUnit.maxValue}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <button className="btn btn-primary">Dodaj</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```